# Automatic vertical alignment of multirow cells

Tags: vertical-alignment, automation, multirow

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{2pt} % height added by \bigstrut
\usepackage{tabu}
\tabulinesep=1.5pt % ensures some offset between cell content and border
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|}
\hline
bigstrut \bigstrut & \\\cline{1-1}
ordinary & \multirow{-2}{*}{Multirow} \\\hline
\shortstack{short \\ stack} & \\\cline{1-1}
ordinary & \multirow{-2}{*}{Multirow} \\\hline
ordinary & \\\cline{1-1}
$x=\int_0^\infty\frac{a}{b}$ & \multirow{-2}{*}{Multirow} \\\hline
ordinary & \\\cline{1-1}
$\displaystyle x=\int_0^\infty\frac{a}{b}$ & \multirow{-2}{*}{Multirow} \\\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

which shows some cases where content of `multirow` cells is not exactly where it should be.

[image: MWE]

I guess a lot of people are familiar with this issue, as I've seen a dozen of workarounds. However all of them required some fine-tuning like `[fixup]`.

I've found a package called `makecell`, which partially makes what I want. Still it has flaws. It won't work for multi-line `multirow` cells and makes problems with `colortbl` package I use for bg colour (`multirow` has to be defined in the first row).

Do you have any ideas on how automatic vertical alignment of `multirow` cell could be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

If an alternative tables package is an option, I'd suggest `cals`:

[image: multirow alignment in calstable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\incell{%\vfil % uncomment to align middle
Multirow}

\begin{calstable}
%\alignC % uncomment to align center
\colwidths{{3cm}{3cm}}
\brow
  \cell{bigstrut \bigstrut}
  \nullcell{tlr}
\erow
\brow
  \cell{ordinary}
  \nullcell{blr}\spancontent{\incell}
\erow
\brow
  \cell{\shortstack{short \\ stack}}
  \nullcell{tlr}
\erow
\brow
  \cell{ordinary}
  \nullcell{blr}\spancontent{\incell}
\erow
\brow
  \cell{ordinary}
  \nullcell{tlr}
\erow
\brow
  \cell{$x=\int_0^\infty\frac{a}{b}$}
  \nullcell{blr}\spancontent{\incell}
\erow
  \brow
  \cell{ordinary}
  \nullcell{tlr}
\erow
\brow
  \cell{$\displaystyle x=\int_0^\infty\frac{a}{b}$}
  \nullcell{blr}\spancontent{\incell}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like I can make an use of your package. Are variable width columns going to be possible any soon?

Comment: Unfortunately, never.